# Having trouble changing the opacity of an image in its onload handler

Tags: javascript, css

I have this bit of JavaScript:

```
function performSearch(keywords) {
  const itemList = document.getElementById('items-div');
  const search = document.getElementById('search');
  itemList.innerHTML = '';
  setLoading(true);

  store.where({ name: keywords }).then((items) => {
    setLoading(false);
    console.log(`Found ${items.length} items...`);

    items.forEach((c, i) => {
      console.log(c);
      if (c.imageUrl) {
        itemList.innerHTML += rowTemplate({
          card: c,
          index: i,
        });
        const img = document.getElementById(`image-${i}`);
        img.onload = () => {
          img.style.transition = "opacity 0.3s";
          img.style.opacity = "1";
          console.log(`Image ${i} loaded succesfully.`);
        };
        img.src = c.imageUrl;
      }
    });

    search.focus();
    search.select();
  });
}
```

The bit that doesn't seem to work is the `img.onload` part.

The `console.log()` message is displayed in the console, however, the opacity does not change.

If I do the exact same thing in the console itself, it works fine.

I realize this must be because the DOM isn't done rendering the stuff I'm adding yet, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I have updated my answer, check it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to specify starter `opacity` on load (it's `1` by default, and you're trying to transition from `1` to `1` which has no visible effect). And you can achieve `fade-in` effect via `@keyframes`, here is an example:

```js
const onload = () => {
  const img = document.getElementById('target');
  img.style.opacity = 0;
  img.style.animation = "fadeIn .5s ease-in 1 forwards";
};

onload();
```

```css
@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" id="target">
```

### UPDATE

*"This sort of displays what I mean: jsfiddle.net/92w79gxa/3 ... in this example, I am showing all of the images by default, but then trying to make them all fade away. Only the last one fades."*

You need to assign new value inside `img.onload`: `img = document.getElementById('some-image-${i}');`. Here is the working example:

```js
const stuff = document.getElementById("stuff");
stuff.innerHTML = '';
console.log('started');
for(let i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
   stuff.innerHTML += `
   <img style="opacity: 1" id="some-image-${i}" width="20" height="20"><br>
   `;

   let img = document.getElementById(`some-image-${i}`);
   console.log('BEFORE "onload"')
   img.onload = () => {
     console.log('INSIDE "onload"')
     img = document.getElementById(`some-image-${i}`);
     img.style.transition = 'opacity 2s';
     img.style.opacity = '0';
   };

   img.src = 'http://synic.world/s/someicon.png';
}

console.log('Done!');
```

```html
<div id="stuff">

</div>
```

If you will look at console logs, you will see, that all iterations goes first, and only after the last one is finished, all `onload` will be executed, and the last stored item will be `.some-image-5` (it's because only last item was faded).

Comment: It's opacity is 0 in css.  Like I said, the same code works in the console: if I do document.getElementById('image').opacity = '1', it works, with the fade-in and everything.

Comment: This sort of displays what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/92w79gxa/3/ ...  in this example, I am showing all of the images by default, but then trying to make them all fade away.  Only the last one fades.

Comment: Yup, that did it.  I'm still not 100% sure how that works, some weird closure trap I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do with the scoping of the for loop. Your JSFiddle example only fades the last image. I used lodash to make sure the scope is correct.

https://jsfiddle.net/92w79gxa/4/

```
const stuff = document.getElementById("stuff");
stuff.innerHTML = '';
_.each(_.range(5), i => {
  stuff.innerHTML += `
<img style="opacity: 1" id="some-image-${i}" width="20" height="20"><br>
`;
})

const images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

_.each(images, (img, i) => {
  img.onload = () => {
    img.style.transition = 'opacity 2s';
    img.style.opacity = '0';
    console.log(`Loaded image ${i}`);
    console.log(img);
  };

  img.src = 'http://synic.world/s/someicon.png';
});
```